# Confirmação DO-WHILE no JAVA

Tags: java, loop

Estou estudando estruturas de repetição em `Java` e fui fazer um exercício relativamente simples, mas não entendo o por que de o código estar dando errado, ele compila, mas entra em looping infinito.
Eu resolvi colocando um if, mas queria entender o que está errado na lógica anterior. Por que `(nome!="0")` não funciona? Eu testei com a idade e funcionou, mas com a string nome não.

```java
/*
 * Faça um programa que leia conjuntos de dois valores, 
 * o primeiro representando o nome do aluno e o segundo representando a sua idade
 * Pare o programa inserindo o valor 0 no campo nome
 */


public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nome;
        int  idade;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Nome: ");
            nome = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Idade: ");
            idade = scan.nextInt();
        } while **(nome!="0")**;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

O `Scanner` vai te retornar um objeto do tipo `String`, e a forma de comparar o seu conteúdo é usando `equals`, assim:

`while (nome.equals("0")) ...`

Veja aqui um exemplo usando as duas comparações e o resultado: [https://onecompiler.com/](https://onecompiler.com/java/3xqmtxda5)

Caso o link fique off, aqui o código completo do exemplo validando a `string`:

```
String nome;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.println("Nome: ");
nome = scan.next();

if (nome == "0") {
    System.out.println("nome == \"0\" é true");
} else {
    System.out.println("nome == \"0\" é false");
}
      
if (nome.equals("0")) {
    System.out.println("name.equals(\"0\") é true");
} else {
    System.out.println("name.equals(\"0\") é false");
}
```